# Converting to PowerShell Dictionary

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I tried using the below script

```
$myDictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content 'YOUR_PATH_HERE')     
$xml.SelectNodes("descendant::node()") | ? Value | % $myDictionary.Add($_.ParentNode.ToString(), $_.Value)  }
```

it worked for me, but it did not solve the complete task as my xml file has different environment specific information.
Can someone suggest a possible solutions for the above requirement in PowerShell Version 2.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following XPath expression for `SelectNodes()` parameter (example for 'UAT' environment) :

```
descendant::environment[@id='UAT']/descendant::text()[normalize-space()]
```

The XPath should return *non-empty text nodes* within the suitable environment (see the XPath [demo](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/PIMVf2-4n)).

Comment: Actually I was using the below script for dictionary conversion,
`$myDictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content 'YOUR_PATH_HERE')     
$xml.SelectNodes("descendant::node()") | ? Value | % $myDictionary.Add($_.ParentNode.ToString(), $_.Value)  }`

Can I use `descendant::environment[@id='UAT']/descendant::text()[normalize-space()]` this in above script?

Comment: @mahesh That what I suggested, try to replace `descendant::node()` in your code with XPath in this answer (I haven't tested it myself)